# creating new iframe after closing old one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Iframe with fields which sent data to php file through ajax. If it was successful I close (it is working) iframe and create new one with another information (doen't work). So question is: how to close the old iframe and open another one?

so here is ajax function that works but doesn't open a new iframe

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "sign.php",
        data: {name : name,
            data: canvasData
            },
        success: function () {

           //frame_activation(); //if it will be here it will open iframe inside the old one iframe. 
            alert('done');
            close_frame (); 
            $(body).html(argument[0]);
            //windows.top.frame_activation();
            frame_activation(); // does't work

        }
    });
```

So the result is - the old iframe sent information and close it, but doesn't open a new iframe.

frame activation :

```
function frame_activation() {   
//document.getElementById('bg_frame').style.visibility = 'visible';
reg = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(reg);
reg.id = 'iframe';
reg.src = 'activate.html';
reg.style.width='600px';
reg.style.height='200px';
position_frame(reg);
reg.style.border='solid 5px #d4d4d4';
alert('here');
return false;
}
```

function to close iframe:

```
function close_frame () {
    parent.document.getElementById('bg_frame').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var el = parent.document.getElementById('iframe');
    el.style.display='none';
    parent.document.body.removeChild(el);   
    return(false);  
}
```

function for creating first iframe with fields

```
function frame_reg() {  
    document.getElementById('bg_frame').style.visibility = 'visible';
    reg = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(reg);
    reg.id = 'iframe';
    reg.src = 'frame.html';
    reg.style.width='640px';
    reg.style.height='400px';
    position_frame(reg);
    reg.style.border='solid 5px #d4d4d4';
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change src of iframe to change a page display.

This is sample using Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnMenu1").click(function () {
         $("#myIframe").attr("src", "example.aspx");
     });
});
```

Comment: the first, if I correct understand you also need to reload iframe. And Also  how to close iframe and open a new one from the code that I provided? it doesn't open a new one.